# How can I remove the new imessage apps and drawing options

Tags: messages, ios

I've just updated my phone to iOS10 and my message app is feeling a little overcrowded. Is it possible to remove these icons from the message app?? It's  a little annoying have a shortcut to the app store forced upon me every time I want to send a message, I guess with the intention to sell animations and gifs to be able to include in messages.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure I'm old and boring, but I just don't want this sort of thing.   If you turn on "reduce motion" in accessibility settings the even more horrible confetti effects go away, and if you press the App store icon above, you can stop apps adding themselves here, but there appears to be no way to get rid of the irritating  grey twistie. I hope someone at Apple is listening to this.

Comment: I'm a relatively young user, but I think that Apple has really forgotten it's customer demographics. There's a large group of users who use iOS due to its simplicity. Also, think about the left handed users trying to reach for the small text box. Now iOS feels more bloated than a new windows laptop.

Comment: If I want to draw, I'll use an app just for drawing. That squiggle icon in messenger shrinks my spacebar and I keep accidentally starting a new line for almost every word. I have extra large hands and fingers and my tiny phone was hard enough to type on as it was. Now it's worse. Get rid of that drawing icon please. Options people! Make it an option!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove them, they're part of Messages.  Once you tap into the tiny text area, the text box expands to hide the buttons.

[image]

Comment: I had hoped, similar to how you could remove the predictive text from the last update that you would be able to remove these in a similar way.

Comment: Not yet.  Perhaps a jailbreak tweak will be developed in the future.

Comment: Are there any alternative apps that just send plain text messages?

Answer (score 0):

Just slide it to the left. It becomes just an arrow >

On phone, will flesh out later.